# Config file for CKEditor doesn't have any effects

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ckeditor, dotnetnuke

I have been working on DNN ASP.NET site and I have used CKEditor in my aspx pages. I would like to exclude autosave plugin and enable automatic spell checker. The code in config.js for the CKEditor is:

```
 CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
    config.removePlugins = 'autosave';
    config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
};
```

But, this config.js doesn't have any effects on my page. Do you have any idea? Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration of CKEditor is managed elsewhere.

Log in as Host

Go to "Host Settings" > "HTML Editor Manager"

There you will find a settings page where you can configure all sort of things, per portal or globally.